# how to update the menu item?

Tags: android, menu-items

I created an application in which I change a menu item, when I check, the application works with the changes. But when I restart the application, I lose the changes, although the file changed are present in internal storage.
i use the function `public boolean onMenuOpened(int featureid, Menu menu) {}` to make the change. I would like to keep a part of the menu and to change the other.

Answer (score 1):

Menu changes aren't saved. You can use [OnPrepareOptionsMenu](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onPrepareOptionsMenu%28android.view.Menu%29) to modify the menu based on some property.

```
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu (Menu menu) {
    if(disableSomething) {
        menu.findItem(R.id.someItemToDisable).setEnabled(false);
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: That combined with SharedPreferences to save whichever options were selected

Comment: can you give me an example, please.